# Jquery scrolling code is jumpy

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

Alright, so I'm making a div scroll left/right when I scroll up/down. It works, but it's all jumpy, and looks ugly. I can't use this for a website as is, so can someone please tell me how to fix the jumpiness? Also, please don't tell me to use plugins.

```
var numScroll = 0;
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(window).scroll(function(event){
                    numScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
                    $("#main").css("top", numScroll + "px");
                    $("#main").css("left", -numScroll + "px");
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the `scroll` event is firing a *lot,* making the browser churn when scrolling.

Why should we not tell you to use plugins? What's the point in duplicating someone else's work? As it would happen, the [jQuery throttle/debounce plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) should work nicely to solve this problem:

```
var numScroll = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $window = $(window);
    var $main = $("#main");

    $window.scroll($.throttle(50, function(event){
        numScroll = $window.scrollTop();
        $main.css({top: numScroll + "px", left: -numScroll + "px"});
    });
}));
```

Note the selector caching for better performance — the less work the browser does on the `scroll` event, the less "jumpy" things will be.

Comment: This didn't work. I didn't even notice a difference from the try without the plugin.